# Union-find algorithm does not return expected result

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, union-find

I implemented the following union-find algorithm using [this](https://medium.com/100-days-of-algorithms/day-41-union-find-d0027148376d) example:

```
import numpy as np


class UnionFind(object):

    def __init__(self, edges):
        self.edges = edges
        self.n_edges = np.max(edges) + 1
        self.data = list(range(self.n_edges))

    def find(self, i):
        if i != self.data[i]:
            self.data[i] = self.find(self.data[i])
        return self.data[i]

    def union(self, i, j):
        pi, pj = self.find(i), self.find(j)
        if pi != pj:
            self.data[pi] = pj

    def run(self):

        for i, j in self.edges:
            self.union(i, j)

        labels = dict()
        for i in range(self.n_edges):
            labels[i] = self.find(i)

        for k, v in labels.items():
            print(k, v)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    edges = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4)] // pairs of equivalent labels
    uf = UnionFind(edges)
    uf.run()
```

I would expect the result to be

```
0 0 
1 1
2 2
3 2
4 2
```

but the algorithm above returns

```
0 0 
1 1
2 3
3 3
4 3
```

That is, I would like the smallest label to be the parent

Is there someone who can point out why this is the case and what I can do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [Union-Find by Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#:~:text=Union%20by%20rank%20always%20attaches,is%20associated%20with%20a%20rank.)

**Code**

[Source](https://python-algorithms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/python_algorithms/basic/union_find.html)

```
class UF:
    """An implementation of union find data structure.
    It uses weighted quick union by rank with path compression.
    """

    def __init__(self, N):
        """Initialize an empty union find object with N items.

        Args:
            N: Number of items in the union find object.
        """

        self._id = list(range(N))
        self._count = N
        self._rank = [0] * N

    def find(self, p):
        """Find the set identifier for the item p."""

        id = self._id
        while p != id[p]:
            p = id[p] = id[id[p]]   # Path compression using halving.
        return p

    def count(self):
        """Return the number of items."""

        return self._count

    def connected(self, p, q):
        """Check if the items p and q are on the same set or not."""

        return self.find(p) == self.find(q)

    def union(self, p, q):
        """Combine sets containing p and q into a single set."""

        id = self._id
        rank = self._rank

        i = self.find(p)
        j = self.find(q)
        if i == j:
            return

        self._count -= 1
        if rank[i] < rank[j]:
            id[i] = j
        elif rank[i] > rank[j]:
            id[j] = i
        else:
            id[j] = i
            rank[i] += 1

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation of the union find object."""
        return " ".join([str(x) for x in self._id])

    def __repr__(self):
        """Representation of the union find object."""
        return "UF(" + str(self) + ")"
```

**Example**

Using your example edges.

```
N = 5
edges = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4)] 

uf = UF(N)

for p, q in edges:
  uf.union(p, q)

uf.show()
```

**Output**

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
2 2
2 2
```

**Comments**

It is not common to show the self edges as edges in undirected graphs.

Thus, rather than

```
edges = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Its more common to have (i.e. just the non-self edges):

```
edges = [(2, 3), (4, 2)]
```

The same output is produced by the above code in either case.

Since self-edges are not shown, you can not get the number of vertices from

```
self.n_edges = np.max(edges) + 1  # not normally correct
```

Number of vertices is normally specified.

Comment: Thank you! But why is `self.n_edges = np.max(edges) + 1` not correct? You also set `N=5`. Where does the 5 come from? Also, `uf.show()` throws an error. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: @random9--Self edges referred to [self loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)) are not allowed in simple graphs.   This makes your edge description `edges = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4)]` unusual since it shows self-loops. Graphs are normally defined by a set of Vertices and Edges.  Normally vertices are numbered from 0 to N-1, where N is the number of vertices.  You normally don't derive the number of vertices from number of the max edge, since this vertex may not have an edge i.e. `edges = [(2, 3), (4, 2)]`, but I could have 10 vertices.

Comment: @random9--[MIT course notes on the definition of graph](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap05.pdf)